# Mediawiki exclude/hide page in internal search

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to use, for example, a magic word on a page so it doesn't appear in the Mediawiki search-bar?

I know there is `__NOINDEX__`, but as I understand, it only excludes your page from Google or other search engines. What I need is, when I type the page on the top right I won't find it. Or at least it won't show me the page as recommended.

Is there a way to archive that?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. See [T24251](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T24251).

Comment: I saw that, but I hoped somebody would still have a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The task does contain a possible workaround (for wikis using [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch)). If this is your own wiki, there are probably a number of other ways inolving various hooks, too.